# In Java, is it possible to bridge ContentHandler to XMLStreamReader

Tags: java, xml, sax, stax

I have a SAX `ContentHandler` and want to bridge this to an StAX `XMLStreamReader`. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

The following (untested) code should provide the “bridge” you require, using an XML copy transformation.

```
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.stax.StAXSource;
import javax.xml.transform.sax.SAXResult;

void bridge(ContentHandler ch, XMLStreamReader sr) {
  StAXSource src = new StAXSource(sr);
  SAXResult res = new SAXResult(ch);
  TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
  Transformer tr = tf.newTransformer();
  tr.transform(src, res);
}
```